# Why new Array(256).join(' ') returns 255 white spaces?

Tags: javascript

```js
let white = new Array(256).join(' ')

console.log(white)
```

Why the following snippet returns string with 255 white spaces? Why not 256?

Comment: because of the count of gaps between the elements.

Comment: because `Array(2).join(' ').length === 1` and `Array(1).join(' ') === 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the relationship **BETWEEN** spaces and the number of characters.
You're adding whitespaces not before or after elements in the array.

```
let white = new Array(n).join(s); // s = n - 1
```

[image: picture]

```js
let string = "One two three four five"; // 5 elements
let spaces = string.split(" ").length - 1;
console.log(spaces); // returns 4
```

Answer (score 4):

Because if your array has *2 elements*, only *1 gap* is between them, so joining them will always result `length - 1`.

Example with more obvious `|` characters. We have `3` empty strings and joining them will return only `2` pipes.

```js
const array = ['', '', ''];

console.log(array.join('|'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You create an array consisting of 256 elements. `join(' ')` will join them to a string by adding a whitespace **in between the elements** (but not before the first or after the last).

Answer (score 0):

As stated in other answers : `.join(' ')` will add the `' '` *between* array elements, and will be repeated only `n-1` times.

---

If your intention is to have a 256 long line of spaces, use the [`String.repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) method :

```
let white = ' '.repeat(256)
```